# Add Facebook scope afterwards

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm working on a web project using Firebase for user authentication.
On of our supported login methods is Facebook. We started with a small set of scope permissions. Everything works well. Now we're at the point where we need **additional scope permissions** from our users to keep the user experience on a high level.

Therefore i got two questions:

1. Is it possible to retrieve a list of already granted scope permissions for each user?
2. How can we add scopes afterwards for user who have been around for a while and just granted a smaller set of scope permissions.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. No, there is no list, you can only check this with a valid User Token and the `/me/permissions` endpoint
2. That depends on your code, but you can just check the authorized permissions when the user hits your page. If permissions are missing, you can logout the user. When he uses the login again, he should get asked for the additional permissions.

Comment: FYI: You don’t need to log the user out, you can just call the login functionality again - if that call contains permissions that have not been asked for before, the dialog to accept or decline them will be shown at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the /me/permissions hint. Works!
I'll check on the second point mentioned by @misorude

Comment: @misorude: i know, but login dialogs need to be called on user interaction, so you cannot just check for existing permissions and immediately open it. if you use the login dialog all the time, there will be an ugly popup that shows up and dissappears immediately :)

Comment: Ah, got you, you want to log out so that the user has to manually hit login again, to avoid the popup blocker. (Alternative could be to not check for the permissions when the user hits the page, but only when they are actually needed.)

Comment: exactly, if he did not authorize all needed permissions, destroy his existing user session so he definitely needs to re-authorize. asking for permissions when they are needed is nice, but you would still have the problem with the popup blocker then - of course, only if you are using a login dialog. no problem with a login redirection (but i am not a fan of those).